# App crashes if I add the GraphViewer Code in onCreate method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-graphview

If I add the GraphViewer Java Code outside of the onCreate method I get the message: `Cannot resolve symbol addSeries`. But when I put the Code in the onCreate method the app crashes after the Splash Screen. Please help ( the code is highlighted between the **):

```
package yourhome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;


import smssca.stefandraegersoftware.de.simplemysqlconnectionapp.datasource.ActivityDataSource;

public class Hauptfenster extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        **GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
                new DataPoint(0, 1),
                new DataPoint(1, 5),
                new DataPoint(2, 3)
        });
        graph.addSeries(series);**
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptfenster);

       final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button lesenBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lesenBtn);
        lesenBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ActivityDataSource(textView).execute("someParams");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hauptfenster, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) { return true;}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: show stacktrace of crash

Comment: What is the crash you get after the splash screen, is it the same as the `Cannot resolve symbol addSeries` message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 1),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3)
    });
graph.addSeries(series);
```

below

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptfenster);
```

these two lines should be first called inside `onCreate` method in most cases

currently you are trying to `findViewById(R.id.graph);` at the moment, when there is no `View`s at all - these are set in `setContentView` below